# Converting rather long time string

Tags: r, datetime, time

I have a bunch of string values that represent date and time and I need to do some math with it (like finding out what's later).  I am stuck with the strptime function. This is what I have. Maybe you guys can help me out a bit.

```
tst1 <- "2013-01-28T11:01:54.385+0430"

#this results in NA: 
y <- strptime(tst1, format="%c")
y <- strptime(tst1, format="%y-%m-%d")
y <- strptime(tst1, format="%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z")

#and this messes the time up: 
y <- strftime(tst1, format="%c")
y <- strftime(tst1, format="%y-%m-%d")
y <- strftime(tst1, format="%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z")
```

Comment: You definitely need an upper case `%Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using

```
strptime("2013-01-28T11:01:54.385+0430", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z")
```

Note the `%Y` because you have a four digit year. Also note that `strptime` is for **p**arsing strings as dates and `strftime` is for **f**ormatting dates as strings.